# Is there a workaround for not fusing the observed data into model definition in Pymc3?

Tags: theano, pymc3

Problem definition: consider the "Simpletest" model (from pymc3 examples)which is something similar to the following one:

```
model = Model()

data = np.random.normal(size=(2, 20))

with model:
    x = Normal('x', mu=.5, tau=2. ** -2, shape=(2, 1))

    z = Beta('z', alpha=10, beta=5.5)

    d = Normal('data', mu=x, tau=.75 ** -2, observed=data)

    step = NUTS()

    trace = sample(1000, step)
```

I'd like to change it so that I'll have a fixed model structure but run the sampling several iterations, each time adding a new data point to the previous (observed) dataset. Since the observed data is somehow embedded inside the model definition, the only way I know to do this is to put the whole model definition inside a loop:

```
model = Model()

# a set of initial data points
data = getInitPoints((2,5))

for i in xrange(m):
    with model:
        x = Normal('x', mu=.5, tau=2. ** -2, shape=(2, 1))

        z = Beta('z', alpha=10, beta=5.5)

        d = Normal('data', mu=x, tau=.75 ** -2, observed=data)

        step = NUTS()

        trace = sample(1000, step)
    data = numpy.vstack( (data,getnewPoint( (2,1) ) ) )
    #use the samples
```

This may produce some unnecessary overhead specially if the model is large. To refrain from the overhead of repeatedly defining the same model, I wonder if there is a solution so that the same results could be achieved with something similar to the following idea:

```
with model:
    x = Normal('x', mu=.5, tau=2. ** -2, shape=(2, 1))

    z = Beta('z', alpha=10, beta=5.5)

data = getInitPoints()

for i in xrange(m):
    # only necessary parts are included in the loop 
    with model:
        d = Normal('data', mu=x, tau=.75 ** -2, observed=data)
                    step = NUTS()
        trace = sample(1000, step)
     data = numpy.vstack((data,getnewPoint()))
```

or even better:

```
data = getInitPoints()
dataHandle = magicHandle(data)
with model:
    x = Normal('x', mu=.5, tau=2. ** -2, shape=(2, 1))

    z = Beta('z', alpha=10, beta=5.5)
    #
    d = Normal('data', mu=x, tau=.75 ** -2, observed=dataHandle)

    step = NUTS()

for i in xrange(m):
    with model:
        trace = sample(1000, step)
    #  
    dataHandle = numpy.vstack((data,getnewPoint()))
```

Comment: I don't even know why the observed data needs to be an argument if it's fixed. Looking forward for an answer to the question .. +1

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's not possible right know. But there is an open issue on this topic with possible solutions here : https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/10